# Reencode MKV (from DVD - Mpeg2) to h264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mkv, dvd

I have some old DVD that I already converted using MakeMKV, they seems to have the original mpeg stream, so I want to do this:

- Reencode the video stream to the more recommended settings for old-DVD using h264.
- Reencode the audio streams (some mkv have 1 or 2 audio tracks) to aac or some other 5channel/stereo more compatible codec.
- I already set the default language for audio and subtitles using mkvtoolnix but in my old TV it plays the first track of audio and the first track of subtitles no matter if other was set as default or not (yes, some of it have 2 subtitle tracks too, VLC loads the defaults ones with no problem).
- Some videos have some interlaced tipical from the old-DVD's so I want to be able to turn on a deinterlace filter too if it is possible.

How can I do this ? Thanks.

```
    ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Volumes/Data/Peliculas-Infantiles/pitufos.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.14.3 (1.3.5/1.4.7) win(x64-release)
    creation_time   : 2019-04-05T17:34:38.000000Z
  Duration: 01:30:34.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6261 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.083417, end 378.378000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 378.378000, end 461.661200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 461.661200, end 644.477167
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 644.477167, end 922.288033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 922.288033, end 1061.927533
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1061.927533, end 1162.194367
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1162.194367, end 1299.965333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1299.965333, end 1393.258533
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 1393.258533, end 1630.829200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 1630.829200, end 1831.329500
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 1831.329500, end 2143.841700
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 2143.841700, end 2327.692033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 2327.692033, end 2545.743200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 2545.743200, end 2748.746000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 2748.746000, end 2863.694167
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 2863.694167, end 3016.680333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 3016.680333, end 3243.573667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 3243.573667, end 3538.368167
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 3538.368167, end 3665.828833
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 3665.828833, end 3910.106200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 3910.106200, end 4237.066167
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 4237.066167, end 4854.850000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 4854.850000, end 5013.708700
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 5013.708700, end 5434.762667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], SAR 186:157 DAR 279:157, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 5484482
      DURATION-eng    : 01:30:34.762666666
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 130304
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 3725857328
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0100E0
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-05 17:34:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:1(por): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:30:34.720000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 169835
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 260866560
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0180BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-05 17:34:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:2(spa): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:30:34.752000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 169836
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 260868096
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0181BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-05 17:34:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:3(por): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 1772
      DURATION-eng    : 01:27:22.759977777
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 660
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1161324
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0120BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-05 17:34:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:4(spa): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 1767
      DURATION-eng    : 01:27:22.759977777
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 660
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1158568
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0122BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.3 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-04-05 17:34:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show info from file and your ffmpeg version. The complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mkv` will suffice.

Comment: I added the `ffmpeg -i input.mkv` info

Comment: Hi, there is some way to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -vf yadif -c:a aac -disposition:a:1 default -disposition:s:1 default output.mkv`. If it doesn't work try again with `-profile:v main` output option.